# imagecreatefromjpeg problem with memory

Tags: php, memory

Hello everyone I am trying to resize an image of 700kb with imagecreatefromjpeg.

This gives the error: Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 25165824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 9356 bytes)

First the memory_limit was 8M then we set this to 24 M but then it still gives the error.
Is this a memory leak? What could have happened? We restarted apache already.

Here is some code for those who are interested:

```
function getResizedBackgroundImageURL($afb="",$params="") {
#1. Verwijder webroot
$filename=C_Settings::getFileRoot().str_replace(C_Settings::getWebRoot(),"",$afb);
$i=strrpos($filename,".");
if ($i!==FALSE) {
    $ext=substr($filename,$i);
    $basefilename=substr($filename,0,$i);

    #Parse width/height params
    $a=explode("&",$params);
    foreach($a as $attr) {
        $b=explode("=",$attr);
        if ($b[0]=="w") {
            $w=$b[1];
        }   elseif ($b[0]=="h") {
            $h=$b[1];
        }
    }

    if (!is_numeric($w)) {
      die("Missing param w for getResizedBackgroundImageURL");
    }

    if (!is_numeric($h)) {
      die("Missing param h for getResizedBackgroundImageURL");
    }

    #Compose new filename
    $newFilename=$basefilename."_w".$w."_h".$h.$ext;
    #See if the resized image exists
    if (!file_exists($newFilename)) {
    if (is_file($filename)) {
        if($ext==".jpg" || $ext==".jpeg"){

            $image_org=imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);


        }
        if($ext==".gif") {
            $image_org=@imagecreatefromgif($filename);
        }

        if ($image_org) {
            list($wp,$hp,$type,$attr)=getimagesize($filename);
            $hfactor=$hp/$h;
            $wfactor=$wp/$w;
            if ($hfactor > $wfactor) {
            $factor=$hfactor;
        } else {
            $factor=$wfactor;
        }   
                if($wp > $w || $hp > $h) {
        $image_w=$wp/$factor;
        $image_h=$hp/$factor;
        }else{
            #if image fits the given boundaries, do not resize
            $image_w=$wp;
        $image_h=$hp;               
        }
        //Note: PHP with GD2.0 required for imagecreatetruecolor
        $img_copy=imagecreatetruecolor($image_w, $image_h);
        imagecopyresampled($img_copy, $image_org, 0, 0, 0, 0, $image_w, $image_h, $wp, $hp);

            if (@imagejpeg($img_copy, $newFilename, 80)) {
                chmod($newFilename,0777);
            }   else {
                echo("<b>Error: </b>Unable to create image $newFilename. Check directory permissions.");
            }   

          imagedestroy($image_org);
            imagedestroy($img_copy);
    }
  }      
    }
    $newURL=C_Settings::getWebRoot().str_replace(C_Settings::getFileRoot(),"",$newFilename);
    return $newURL;     
}
```

}

Comment: I had this problem recently. Setting your memory to 64M should fix, some jpeg require tonnes of memory for some reason.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Increase your memory until you have enough and make sure you use imagedestroy() when your done with your processing.

```
ini_set("memory_limit","10000M");
```

Comment: that's what i did. 30 M was enough

Comment: What are the disadvantages of increasing the memory_limit ?